# Pytorch - Using more GPUs and increasing batch size makes training slower in DistributedDataParallel

Tags: parallel-processing, pytorch, distributed-system

I am trying to implement StyuleGAN2. My code works well when I am just using single GPU to do the training. I would like to speed up the training by utlilizing 8 GPUs by using DistributedDataParallel. However, I noticed that using more GPUs does not speed up the training for me at all. Instead, using more GPUs makes the training slower.

I also tried to modify the batch size and I noticed that batch size = 8 trains the model fastest. Increasing the batch size will makes the training significantly slower.

I tried to measure the time for each epoch and found the training time is significantly longer every 4 epochs.

```
EP0_elapsed_time: 3.3021082878112793 sec
EP1_elapsed_time: 0.8542821407318115 sec
EP2_elapsed_time: 0.7720010280609131 sec
EP3_elapsed_time: 7.11009407043457 sec
EP4_elapsed_time: 0.7670211791992188 sec
EP5_elapsed_time: 0.7623276710510254 sec
EP6_elapsed_time: 0.7690849304199219 sec
EP7_elapsed_time: 7.0614259243011475 sec
EP8_elapsed_time: 0.7806422710418701 sec
EP9_elapsed_time: 0.7751979827880859 sec
EP10_elapsed_time: 0.7685496807098389 sec
EP11_elapsed_time: 7.09734845161438 sec
EP12_elapsed_time: 0.7923364639282227 sec
EP13_elapsed_time: 0.7789566516876221 sec
EP14_elapsed_time: 0.7974681854248047 sec
EP15_elapsed_time: 7.120237350463867 sec
```

I notice a similar post and it has not been solved.
[No speedup doing multi GPU training with DistributedDataParallel vs. single GPU](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/no-speedup-doing-multi-gpu-training-with-distributeddataparallel-vs-single-gpu/33633)

How can I solve this issue?

main()

```
def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  
  parser.add_argument('-n', '--nodes', default=1, type=int, metavar='N')
  parser.add_argument('-g', '--gpus', default=1, type=int, help='number of gpus per node')
  parser.add_argument('-nr', '--nr', default=0, type=int, help='ranking/index within the nodes')
  parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=400, type=int, metavar='N', help='number of total epochs to run')
  parser.add_argument('--model_dir', default='stylegan2ada_002', type=str, help='model dir name')
  parser.add_argument('--train_img_dir_path', default='./GAN/clean_2', type=str, help='training images dir path')
  parser.add_argument('--img_size', default=64, type=int, help='target image size')
  parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=32, type=int, help='batch size')
  parser.add_argument('--g_latent_dim', default=512, type=int, help='dim of generator noise z and w')
  parser.add_argument('--mn_num_layers', default=8, type=int, help='number of layers in the mapping network (8 according to paper)')
  parser.add_argument('--g_lr', default=1e-3, type=float, help='generator learning rate')
  parser.add_argument('--d_lr', default=1e-3, type=float, help='discriminator learning rate')
  parser.add_argument('--mn_lr', default=1e-5, type=float, help='mapping network learning rate')
  parser.add_argument('--adam_betas', default=(0.0, 0.99), type=tuple, help='betas of adam optimizers')
  parser.add_argument('--gradient_accumulate_steps', default=1, type=int, help='gradient accumulate steps')
  parser.add_argument('--lazy_gradient_penalty_interval', default=4, type=int, help='lazy gradient penalty interval')
  parser.add_argument('--lazy_path_penalty_after', default=5000, type=int, help='the point that starts to apply lazy path penalty')
  parser.add_argument('--lazy_path_penalty_interval', default=32, type=int, help='lazy path penalty interval')
  parser.add_argument('--gradient_penalty_coefficient', default=10., type=float, help='gradient penalty coefficient')
  parser.add_argument('--style_mixing_prob', default=0.9, type=float, help='style mixing prob')
  parser.add_argument('--generate_img_interval', default=100, type=int, help='generate images every x epochs')
  parser.add_argument('--generate_img_after_percent', default=0.4, type=float, help='generate images after y% of the total epochs')

  args = parser.parse_args()

  args.world_size = args.gpus * args.nodes
  args.distributed = True
  args.dist_backend = 'nccl'
  args.dist_url = 'env://'

  os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = 'localhost'
  os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '7788'

  mp.spawn(train, nprocs=args.gpus, args=(args,))
```

train()

```
def train(gpu, args):

  rank = args.nr * args.gpus + gpu

  torch.cuda.set_device(gpu)

  dist.init_process_group(
    backend=args.dist_backend,
    init_method=args.dist_url,
    world_size=args.world_size,
    rank=rank,
  )

  dist.barrier()

  # Measure time
  start_init = time.time()
  
  # Make dirs
  ### Create model dir if not existed
  model_dir_path = f'./{args.model_dir}'
  if not (os.path.exists(model_dir_path)):
    try:
      os.makedirs(model_dir_path)
    except:
      pass

  ### Create 'images' dir if not existed
  img_dir_path = f'./{args.model_dir}/images'
  if not (os.path.exists(img_dir_path)):
    try:
      os.makedirs(img_dir_path)
    except:
      pass

  ### Create 'checkpoints' dir if not existed
  ckpt_dir_path = f'./{args.model_dir}/checkpoints'
  if not (os.path.exists(ckpt_dir_path)):
    try:
      os.makedirs(ckpt_dir_path)
    except:
      pass
  
  # Dataset and Dataloader
  ### Create the dataset
  dataset = ImageDataset(path=args.train_img_dir_path, image_size=args.img_size)
  sampler = torch.utils.data.distributed.DistributedSampler(
    dataset,
    num_replicas=args.world_size,
    rank=rank,
  )
  ### Create the dataloader
  dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset,
    batch_size=args.batch_size,
    num_workers=0,
    shuffle=False,
    drop_last=True,
    pin_memory=True,
    sampler=sampler,
  )


  # Initialization
  ### Setup gpu device
  device = torch.device('cuda', rank)
  ### Get log2 of the target image size
  log_resolution = log2(args.img_size)
  ### Create discriminator
  discriminator = Discriminator(log_resolution)
  ### Put the discriminator to the device
  discriminator.to(device)
  ### Apply DDP
  discriminator = nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(discriminator, device_ids=[gpu])
  ### Create discriminator loss
  discriminator_loss = DiscriminatorLoss().to(device)
  ### Create discriminator optimizer
  discriminator_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    discriminator.parameters(),
    lr = args.d_lr,
    betas = args.adam_betas,
  )
  ### Create gradient penalty (gp) loss
  gradient_penalty = GradientPenalty()

  ### Create generator
  generator = Generator(device, log_resolution, args.g_latent_dim, args.style_mixing_prob)
  ### Put the generator to the device
  generator.to(device)
  ### Apply DDP
  generator = nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(generator, device_ids=[gpu])
  ### Create generator loss
  generator_loss = GeneratorLoss().to(device)
  ### Create generator optimizer
  generator_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    generator.parameters(),
    lr = args.g_lr,
    betas = args.adam_betas,
  )
  ### Create path length penalty (PLP) loss
  path_length_penalty = PathLengthPenalty(0.99).to(device)

  ### Create mapping network
  mapping_network = MappingNetwork(args.g_latent_dim, args.mn_num_layers)
  ### Put the mapping network to the device
  mapping_network.to(device)
  ### Apply DDP
  mapping_network = nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(mapping_network, device_ids=[gpu])
  ### Create mapping network optimizer
  mapping_network_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(
    mapping_network.parameters(),
    lr = args.mn_lr,
    betas = args.adam_betas,
  )

  generate_img_after = int(args.epochs * args.generate_img_after_percent)

  # Measure time
  torch.cuda.synchronize()
  end_init = time.time()
  init_time = end_init - start_init

  print(f'Init_time: {init_time} sec')

  # Training steps and losses tracking
  disc_loss_y = []
  gen_loss_y = []

  # Measure time
  times = []

  for i in range(args.epochs):
    start_epoch = time.time()

    disc_loss, gen_loss = step(
      i,
      device,
      args.batch_size,
      dataloader,
      args.gradient_accumulate_steps,
      args.style_mixing_prob,
      discriminator,
      discriminator_loss,
      discriminator_optimizer,
      gradient_penalty,
      args.gradient_penalty_coefficient,
      args.lazy_gradient_penalty_interval,
      generator,
      generator_loss,
      generator_optimizer,
      path_length_penalty,
      args.g_latent_dim,
      args.lazy_path_penalty_after,
      args.lazy_path_penalty_interval,
      mapping_network,
      mapping_network_optimizer,
      args.model_dir,
      args.generate_img_interval,
      generate_img_after,
    )

    # Measure time
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    end_epoch = time.time()
    elapsed = end_epoch - start_epoch
    times.append(elapsed)

    print(f'EP{i}_elapsed_time: {elapsed} sec')

    ### Append losses of each step into the lists
    disc_loss_y.append(disc_loss)
    gen_loss_y.append(gen_loss)

  # Measure time
  avg_time = sum(times)/args.epochs
  print(f'avg_time: {avg_time} sec')

  ### Plot the losses
  epoch_x = np.linspace(1, args.epochs, args.epochs).astype(int)
  plt.plot(epoch_x, disc_loss_y, label='disc_loss')
  plt.plot(epoch_x, gen_loss_y, label='gen_loss')
  plt.legend()
  plt.savefig(f'{img_dir_path}/loss.png')
```